# Javascript how to find option values in object loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following objects in javascript:

```
var group = {
        'object1': {
            option1: '',
            option2: false
        },
        'object2': {
            option1: '',
            option2: true
        },
        'object3': {
            option1: '',
            option2: true
        }
    };
```

How can I loop through `group` in order to find every `object` that has an `option2` of `true`?

For example, giving me an array of `['object2', 'object3']`

Comment: **Note:** Do not rely on objects to give you consistent order. Different JS engines behave differently. If order matters, use an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var group = {
    'object1': {
        option1: '',
        option2: false
    },
    'object2': {
        option1: '',
        option2: true
    },
    'object3': {
        option1: '',
        option2: true
    }
};

var filtered = [];

for (var i in group){
    if (group[i].option2 === true){
        filtered.push(i);
    }
}

// filtered is now ['object2', 'object3']
```

Comment: `if (group[i].option2 === true){` can be shortened to `if (group[i].option2){`

Answer (score 2):

You can take a functional approach using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
var group = {
    'object1': {
        option1: '',
        option2: false
    },
    'object2': {
        option1: '',
        option2: true
    },
    'object3': {
        option1: '',
        option2: true
    }
};

var match= Object.keys(group).filter(function(val) {
  return group[val].option2;
});

document.body.innerHTML= JSON.stringify(match);
```

Comment: Returning `val` potentially may give false negative results if a key is an empty string. Why don't you just return `true` there?

Comment: Is there a functional way of filtering the list of objects themselves and not just the keys?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, good question.  I looked at jQuery's source, and it uses "for in" when using `map` and `each` on objects.  That seems to imply that there's no functional equivalent in JavaScript.